# No funciona mi xlwings cuando lo compilo con pyintsaller pero si cuando lo corro en jupyter

Tags: pyinstaller, openpyxl

No funciona mi código cuando lo compilo con `pyinstaller -onefile` pero si cuando lo corro en `jupyter notbooks`, ¿Alguna idea cómo solucionarlo?

Este es mi código:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import requests
import xlwings as xw
import tabulate
import sys
import getpass
import PySimpleGUI as sg


try:
    wworkbook = xw.Book(r"Feeder_Auto_OFD.xlsm") 
except:
    print("Error reading Feeder restart the tool")
   
sheet1 = workbook.sheets['Dashboard'].used_range.value
galileo = pd.DataFrame(sheet1,columns=['Country','Mothership','Node','ToT. Intake','OFD PRJ','Cap Breach','Bottleneck','GT Exp Side','Webhook','msg'])
galileo=galileo[['Node','Mothership','Webhook','msg','OFD PRJ']]
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Aparece algún error? ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? Por favor oprime [edit] y aclara lo que sucede en cada ambiente de trabajo.

Comment: [Solo decir que no funciona no es de mucha utilidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/21). Usualmente hay mensajes específicos de error, archivos de log, o algo que explica cuál es el problema.